# Meaning of Right$(string, 3)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was reading through some source code and came across what looks like a call to a function:

```
Right$(string, 3)
```

I can understand this is just simple string manipulation, but what is the meaning of the $ symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ has no meaning in context of Right function. In ancient VB Right$ was a function in new VB it is Right but you can also use Right$ (for backward compatibility)

`Right$("hasan", 3)` and `Right("hasan", 3)` are same in VB.NET

It is merely a convention used to name String related functions.

Comment: Okay - so I can simply remove this confusing symbol?

Comment: @m.edmondson yes in latest vb.net you can remove it

Answer (score 3):

This is used to call the string-function Right() and not the variant-function Right().

```
& -> Long
% -> Integer
# -> Double
! -> Single
@ -> Decimal
$ -> String
```

The Right() function takes take a "variant" as input, and return a "variant". This is not optimal when using on strings. Using Right$() takes a string and returns a string and is therefore faster. Not sure if this is still true in VB.net

Comment: True enough, but not an answer to this question. This question is about the meaning of `$` on a *function* not a *variable*

Comment: In VB.Net `Right` only exists as a string function. There is no variant version like there was in VB6 (there are no variants!). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxs6hz0a(VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is a legacy from old VB, meaning its a string function. It was likely carried over for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The $ sign was used to denote the variable type *long, long* ago in VB6 for ***both functions and variables***. They were never recommended to be used on variables as they should have always been explicitly declared like below:

```
Dim myValue As String
```

and not a great practice to use:

```
myValue$ = ""
```

However once upon a time, it was good practice to use on certain functions like the **Right() function** which took a **Variant** type. Variants could be any type of variable and were considered bad from a performance standpoint. When using strings with a function like Right(), Left(), Mid(), etc. it was better to be explicit and indicate it was a String for performance reasons like below:

```
Right$(myValue, 3)
```

The only exception to this practice was with the Replace() function.

Now the only reason it is kept in the .NET Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace is for grandfathering or converting VB6 code into VB.NET for compatibility reasons. There is no need to write new code using the notation that indicates you are using a String type with those functions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic)

The default type may be overridden for a specific declaration by using a special suffix character on the variable name (`#` for `Double`, `!` for `Single`, `&` for `Long`, `%` for `Integer`, `$` for `String`, and `@` for `Currency`) - The same is true for the return type of a function.

In VB6 the Right function returns a variant, so in your example it ensures that the `Right` function returns a string.

Comment: True enough, but not an answer to this question. This question is about the meaning of `$` on a *function* not a *variable*